# Query is executing in sqldbx but not in SSRS ( Visual Studio 2010 )

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

My query is as follows :

```
SELECT LBrCode, PrdAcctId, EffFromDate, ACTUALDATE, ACTUALDATENEW, IdealBalDate, IdealBal,
 SancDate, TotSancLimit, ExpDate, NoOfInstl, InstlstartDt, InstlAmt, DpDate, TotalDpArrived, TotalDpAllowed, NEWDATE, IdealBalNew
, sum(z.IdealBalNew) OVER (partition BY z.LBrCode, z.PrdAcctId, datepart(MM, z.NEWDATE), datepart(yyyy, z.NEWDATE) ORDER BY LBrCode, PrdAcctId, NEWDATE) NEWESTBALANCE

FROM (

SUB QUERY

) z
--GROUP BY z.LBrCode, z.PrdAcctId, z.EffFromDate
ORDER BY LBrCode, PrdAcctId, EffFromDate
```

In the above query  , When i comment the " sum(z.IdealBalNew) OVER " columns , the query is accepted in SSRS Report dataset . But with  sum(z.IdealBalNew) OVER  column it gives error . Error is : Incorrect syntax near "order" , Incorrect syntax near "z" , Microsoft sql error : 102. Same query executes properly in sqldbx database.

Any issue regarding  " `sum() OVER partition order by` " not being supported by SSRS Visual Studio 2010 ?

Comment: The error doesn't appear to be related to VS or SSRS, but simply a SQL error. You can try running your query in SSMS to get a better understanding of the issue. It appears to be a typo in your subquery.

Answer (score 0):

> Any issue regarding " sum() OVER partition order by " not being
>   supported by SSRS Visual Studio 2010 ?

No, there is no such known issue.   Probably you have a typo or some other difference in your SSRS code.